# Submitting changes to git submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-fork

I am working on machine learning with node.js. There are several different projects for different methods, and I want to use all of them for comparison, so I created a parent repository [machine-learning](https://github.com/erelsgl/machine-learning), that contains several (currently two) submodules: "perceptron" and "classifier". The two submodules are forks that I made from other repositories.

Now, while I work on the main machine-learning project, I sometimes make slight modifications to code in the submodules. But when I try to commit my changes (to my fork), it doesn't work:

```
erelsgl@erelsgl-H61MLC:~/git/machine-learning$ git commit -a
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   classifier (modified content, untracked content)
#   modified:   perceptron (untracked content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

erelsgl@erelsgl-H61MLC:~/git/machine-learning$ git add .

erelsgl@erelsgl-H61MLC:~/git/machine-learning$ git commit -a
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   classifier (modified content, untracked content)
#   modified:   perceptron (untracked content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

How can I commit my changes to the submodules?

I am not sure submodules are the way to go - maybe there is a better way to use several sub-projects in a single main project, so that I can also submit changes to each subproject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first `cd` into a submodule and commit your changes there (it's basically a separate repo). Then in your parent repo you'll see that the submodule was updated to a new commit and you'll record (`add` and `commit`) this fact in your main repo.

It should look like this:

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
modified:   classifier (new commits)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works from the command line, however, when I try to commit from Eclipse (using the EGit plugin), I get, in additional to the single file I changed, ALL files in the folder as "removed", and the same files as "new" in a subfolder. For example, the file "README.md" is marked as "removed", and the file "classifier/README.md" is marked as "new".

Comment: That's probably an EGit issue. Byt the way, [screenshots for 1.3 release](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/1.3#Submodule_Support) (which was the first to include submodules support) suggest that submodules are handled separately.